# How to use WSUS Administration APIs in an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

We've got an old solution that uses the WSUS Administration APIs (`Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.dll`) with an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API. In order to get it working, I need to recompile it and so have upgraded it to .NET 8.0 but then the WSUS API's seem to break.

I thought I could reference the `Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.dll` in a separate .NET Standard 2.0 wrapper library, which builds and runs, but as soon as the code tries to execute, I get:

[image: FileNoteFoundException]

I'm referencing the WSUS APIs from: `C:\Program Files\Update Services\Api`

My understanding is that .NET Standard 2.0 should support .NET Framework dll's, so I"m confused why it's not working here? Is this at all possible, and if not, are there any alternatives for WSUS Administration APIs for .NET 8.0?